# Good VPN softwares

Tags: vpn

I recently posted an AD on kijiji.ca using the Opera VPN. But Seems they deleted it.
What could be the reason for this. I was surprised that they could detect that I am using 
VPN. On asking them here is the reply I received :

```
    You ads are not being posted correctly since it appears that you are using
 3rd party software or browser add-ons/extensions eg: ad blockers, VPN's or proxy 
services, etc that is limiting Kijiji's ability to correctly communicate with your browser
```

Does that mean the Kijiji could detect if I am behind a VPN ? 
 Is there an alternative 
to it or to avoid getting detected ?

Comment: The real question is why do you want to use VPN at all.

Answer (score 2):

VPNs are usually hosted on servers/VPSes that come from predictable subnets (i.e., their IPs share known prefixes). So people can predict that you're using a VPN. There might be other methods to detect popular VPN services, I don't know.

Your only alternative is to either buy a server with a "good" IP (no idea how, ask the support staff of the hosting company), or to buy a premium VPN service that explicitly markets its "undiscoverability" (web-searching for `netflix VPN` might help).

VPNs can also block ads via DNS, which is detectable by the websites, as their ads won't load.